# Predict product returns in e-commerce

Tags: python, tensorflow, prediction

I was trying to build a NN model using TF by following this article on the internet [link](http://aisel.aisnet.org/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1369&context=icis2015)

As of now, I have been able to use some code online [link](https://github.com/JRMeyer/tensorflow-tutorial/blob/master/logistic_regression_train.py)

This uses a Logistic regression in TF, and the tries to predict a binary classification in [1 0] pattern, where [1 0] & [0 1] is is not-returned & returned respectively.

I have 13 feature set and 1 label, but post training the model predicts at an accuracy of around 40%

I have also used Sklearn's scaler to scale the feature set in -1,1.

Is there a definite way to tackle this problem for a beginner?

Comment: No, there isn't. Question answered.

Comment: Could be all sorts of things. Your features could be non-indicative for the prediction you are trying to make. Your training data set could be too small. Your network architecture might be inappropriate for the task. You might be having overfitting issues etc. Neural networks are complex and there is no canned solution to the question of "Why doesn't my network predict?". Either start reading up on it, or as suggested, try some other classification algorithms from scikit-learn. Those are much easier to use out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried other learning models such as a Decision Tree (and by extension Random Forest), or perhaps XGBoost?  In small experiments, I found those to be better at classifying over a neural network.

You could also spend a few minutes reading up on feature engineering to some other ideas for getting better results from your classifier.